# How to add $ sign to chart values in Line chart view using achartengine

Tags: achartengine, linechart

How to add $ symbol with chart values in Line chart view using android achartengine.

Like $2, $3...

Comment: Where are you trying to add them?

Comment: I want to display $ symbol with chart values(setDisplayChartValues) like $2, $3 in android achartengine graph

Comment: That is not supported.

Comment: @Dan.. Thanks for d information

Answer (score 0):

You can add annotation to series at points ..

```
firstSeries.addAnnotation("$1", 1, 1);
firstSeries.addAnnotation("$2", 2, 4);
firstSeries.addAnnotation("$3", 3, 9);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check and let you know what happened